# Getting yeoman/usermin to uglify .kml file references

Tags: javascript, yeoman, uglifyjs

I am attempting to use yeoman to scafold a web site, my website includes references to files such as images/foo.kml

Running Grunt results in these files being filerev, i.e. the file images/foo.kml is copied to the dist directory but now called images/3333.foo.kml.

The only problem is that usermin task does not replace the references to images/foo.kml in the requested javascript file, but it does manage to process all the references to css and javascript files.

References to images, css and javascript files are normally listed by html tags, eg ,  etc.  In my case I am making a programmtic request to a kml file which is used by a bit of add hock javascript, can usermin deal with type of problem?  Or would I be better off putting all of the files that are going to be accessed by a javascript application in a different directory and ensure that references to these files are not subject to filerev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line I was using OpenLayers to process the kml files, as the files are not used my img tags and only by a Java script program, the file name has to remain a constant. Since the uglify task has no concept of understanding a file name within a block of Javascript.

My solution was to change the grunt file so that my kml files are copied from the app to the dist directory.